# MediatR command inside Azure Function ServiceBusTrigger

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues, mediatr

Using some references, I have created the `Azure Function App` with Clean Architecture and the Project structure looks like this:

[image]

My Azure Function is of the type `Service Bus Queue Trigger`. Basically, I want to Call `MediatR` command `CreateProductCommand` inside this function trigger. So that, whenever there is a message pushed into Service bus Queue, I can read that and save that into SQL database using this `MediatR` command. `CreateProductCommand` has EF Core implementation.

```
public class SaveProductDataToDatabase
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public SaveProductDataToDatabase(IMediator mediator)
        {
            _mediator = mediator;
        }

        [FunctionName("SaveProductDataToDatabase")]
        public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("product-data-dev-01", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"Processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how to use the `CreateProductCommand` inside this function trigger. Please help.

Comment: How come this Clean architecture causes so much headache. What is a single benefit of trying to force that paradigm on Function? Function itself is a handler. It doesn't need MediatR abstraction.

Comment: @SeanFeldman what's best approach to deal with it? We have multiple data sources EF Core and File Streams. They can be switched based on certain business use-cases.

Comment: It’s hard answering a specific question “what to do” w/o knowing the details. Resembles asking a doctor the same question by just letting know you have a pain. It could be a lack of sleep or a cancer, only details can lead to an effective recommendation. In your case, it _sounds_ like the data sources need to be abstracted so the function can perform its work w/o carrying for the details. But function is your handler. Abstracting it with MediatR feels not only unnecessary. Not to mention the grief it will add to the library author. A blog post by the library author would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Adding MediatR command handler on top of a function is redundant as function is already a handler in itself and a small unit of work. A function has a single responsibility usually that responsibility is encapsulated in the function code. Unless your function has multiple responsibilities, which it shouldn’t, MediatR is unnecessary.

Comment: how about adding repository pattern or calling dbcontext directly?

Comment: Hmmm, interesting point of view but shouldn't it be responsible rather for Http stuff like producing responses, passing to the business logic DTO instead of the request etc?

Comment: Depending on the context and how you implement things, implementation can change. For instance, you could bind your HTTP request to a strongly typed DTO and not deal with HTTP primitives. Functions' nature should be scoped and small. If all you do is persist or query and return, I'm not entirely sure the complexity is justified. Leaving alone hip and clean, there shouldn't be some pragmatic thought as well.